# FBX models look like folded in three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, fbx

recently I started working with models from mixamo.
To give those models several animations I first extracted animations from some meshes, put them together and gave them to all the fbx- meshes.
That worked most of the times.

Then I got aware that these animations can be simply downloaded and so did I using a similar procedure to collect some animations and share them with the meshes.

BUT now the meshes zombie- look like

[image]

[image]

Is this a known issue ? I know the odds are against me as many people use mixamo. If someone already stumbled about it, please be so kind and tell me a solution.

Thanks for your time.

edit:

[image]

Comment: Can you please try it with the latest version of `FBXLoader`? Today's release `r125` might help to solve this issue.

Comment: I am glad I did not say "Of course I can" because when I downloaded three.js 125, uploaded it to the server and made some adjustments in the index.html, I got lots of error messages which tells me that the three- infrastructures has...changed. 
So I integrated the newer fbx- loader into my threejs124 environment, to be told that it is in need of "fflate.min" which I also uploaded. 
If it is o.k. so usinf the 124 build I have to tell that the outcome is the same.

Comment: Can you please share the FBX file in this thread?

Comment: Maybe I might mention that the reason I tried to change the method I shuffeled together was that some meshes showed weird behaviour like being stuck in their T-Pose and looking like they are straight falling on their "faces"...

I will try to add a picture.

Comment: "THE" fbx file ?
There is alway a fbx model without animation and there are several animations which are added to the mesh.
I already tried to put a stringified animation into the editor but it complained about the length as "only" 30.000 characters were allowed.

Comment: Here we go...
https://jsfiddle.net/ko89byds/